# SQL query : select employees from each company having max salary,

Tags: sql, derby, greatest-n-per-group

Hi i have written a SQL query for Derby database, which fetches an employee from each company having max salary

these are the table structure

```
 create table Company_Tbl_One(
    company_Id int primary key,
    company_name varchar(100)
 )

 create table Employee_Tbl_One(
    employee_Id int primary key,
    employee_name varchar(100),
    company int references Company_Tbl_One
 )

 alter table Employee_Tbl_One add salary int

 insert into Company_Tbl_One values(12,'Facebook Inc');
 insert into Company_Tbl_One values(11,'Google Inc');
 insert into Company_Tbl_One values(10,'Yahoo Inc');
 insert into Company_Tbl_One values(14,'AOL Inc');

 insert into EMPLOYEE_TBL_ONE(employee_Id,employee_name,company,salary) values(1, 'Tom Jackson',12,1000);
 insert into EMPLOYEE_TBL_ONE(employee_Id,employee_name,company,salary) values(2, 'Jimmy John',12,200);
 insert into EMPLOYEE_TBL_ONE(employee_Id,employee_name,company,salary) values(3, 'Samual Jackson',11,2000);
 insert into EMPLOYEE_TBL_ONE(employee_Id,employee_name,company,salary) values(4, 'Sam Raime',10,3000);
 insert into EMPLOYEE_TBL_ONE(employee_Id,employee_name,company,salary) values(5, 'Tidy Mann',14,5000);
 insert into EMPLOYEE_TBL_ONE(employee_Id,employee_name,company,salary) values(6, 'Oliver Stone',14,5300);
 insert into EMPLOYEE_TBL_ONE(employee_Id,employee_name,company,salary) values(7, 'Falcon Gonzalies',10,3300);
 insert into EMPLOYEE_TBL_ONE(employee_Id,employee_name,company,salary) values(8, 'Ister Jack',11,2300);
```

the sql query is as follows

```
select e.employee_name, c.company_name
from    EMPLOYEE_TBL_ONE e,
    COMPANY_TBL_ONE c,
    (select max(salary) as SALARY,
            company as COMPANY_ID 
            from EMPLOYEE_TBL_ONE group by COMPANY) x
where   c.company_Id = x.COMPANY_ID 
and     e.salary = x.SALARY
and     e.company = c.company_Id
```

Now the above sql query works fine and fetches me results,

But are there any other way of writing sql query for the same problem statement ?

Comment: Unrelated but: you should start using explicit `JOIN`s in the `FROM` clause not implicit joins in the where clause. Regarding your question: as Derby lacks window functions, I don't see another way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Why do you need multiple ways to write your query? Is the one that you've identified inadequate for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

another way using `not exists` i.e. select all employees where another employee with a higher salary does not exist

```
select e.employee_name, c.company_name, e.salary
from EMPLOYEE_TBL_ONE e
join COMPANY_TBL_ONE c on e.company = c.company_Id     
where not exists (
    select 1 from EMPLOYEE_TBL_ONE e2
    where e2.company = e.company
    and e2.salary > e.salary
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function RANK of SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM Company_Tbl_One C
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT *, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Company ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS rank
  FROM Employee_Tbl_One
) E
ON C.company_Id = E.company
AND E.rank = 1
```

Edit: Sorry, thought it was MSSQL